# Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a new PL/SQL user. I tried to create a procedure and run it like:

```
create or replace procedure addp1(i in number) is

begin
  insert into t3 values (i,'xxxx');
end addp1;

begin
addp1(99);
end;
```

but i got `error: Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"`  in my log file. Can anyone help me fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: The Procedure is created only after issuing a '/'. So, it says.. after end.. encountered begin..!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure addp1(i in number) 
is
begin
  insert into t3 values (i,'xxxx');
end addp1;
/* We have to actually push the block to the engine by issuing a '/' */
/

begin
addp1(99);
end;
/* Every PL/SQL Block needs this! */
/
```

Comment: Damn! Is there any reference to the documentation that says this ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-D60DC309-B03B-4B4A-AF65-46B17FA38E1C